# "feed an animal some food?"

Tags: prepositions

Which sentence is correct? (or both)

*Feed the dog twice a day this meat.*

*Feed the dog twice a day with this meat.*

Comment: "Feed this meat to the dog, twice a day"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd change the word order:

"Feed the dog this meat twice a day."

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/feed

Comment: And clearly let the poor thing go hungry on the other five!

Comment: Is this about grammar or about how often a dog should be fed, now? :D

Comment: I think the dog goes vegetarian on the other five! :-D

Comment: I've edited it!

Comment: Given the Macmillan dictionary examples and yours it seems that "feed an animal on/with/no preposition some food" are all correct. Am I correct?

Comment: @Peter, no, that's not quite correct; to be "the dog was fed meat" means that the dog received meat for one particular meal.  "The dog was fed on meat" means that the dog customarily received meat for most of its meals.  "The dog was fed with meat" is wrong, as far as I'm concerned; "with" is used to describe the manner of feeding, or in a metaphorical sense, the thing being given; but not the type of food.  So you might say "The dog was fed with care" or "we fed his ego with lies".